# MsBuild: Add text or custom information to the files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

The below code works fine to copy the files from `Source` to the `Destination folder`. I want to make the copied files in order for example `1.zip.exe  2.NetFx.exe` etc... or `I.zip.exe  II.NetFx.exe`etc....

Basically I want to tell the user to install the tools in order. How can I do this??? Please give me some idea...!

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OutDir)'==''">
          <OutDir>..\..\..\OutputSetup\</OutDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <SourceFiles Include="..\tools\zip\**\*.*"/>
        <SourceFiles Include="..\tools\NetFx\**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>


    <Target Name="CopyTools">

            <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@($(OutDir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </Target>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Ordering in MSBuild is imposed by [target dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx): DependsOnTargets, BeforeTargets, AfterTargets. If you want a guaranteed order of execution, create separate targets for those items and set up dependencies between those.

Comment: @Seva Titov: I want to tell the user install by order, so I want to mark the tools by order like `1.zip.exe 2.NetFx.exe` Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can solve this issue as following a code like below:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OutDir)'==''">
  <OutDir>..\..\..\OutputSetup\</OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <SourceFiles Include="..\tools\zip\**\*.*">
       <Number>1</Number>
    </SourceFiles>
    <SourceFiles Include="..\tools\NetFx\**\*.*">
       <Number>2</Number>
    </SourceFiles>
</ItemGroup>


<Target Name="CopyTools">

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@($(OutDir)\%(SourceFiles.Number)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</Target>
```